# Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies. Issue found: Invalid Data safety form. What is the solution?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, privacy-policy

My app update on the google play store is rejected and I got this mail from the google play store :

```
Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies
Issue found: Invalid Data safety form
We reviewed your app’s Data safety form in Play Console and found discrepancies between it and how the app collects and shares user data. All apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety form that discloses their data collection and sharing practices - this is required even if your app does not collect any user data.

We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app’s Data safety form as user data collected.

Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

SPLIT_BUNDLE 6: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID)
About the Data safety section in Google Play User Data Policy
Your app must be in compliance with this policy. If your app continues to be non-compliant after August 22, 2022, your app updates will be rejected and your app may face additional enforcement actions in the future.

Please make changes to align your app’s Data safety form with the app’s behavior. This can be done by either:

Updating your form in Play Console to declare the collection of Data Types noted below; or
Removing unwanted functionality and attributable code that collects this user data from your app or libraries used in your app, and when applicable to deactivate all non-compliant APKs.
To deactivate non-compliant APKS, you can create a new release and upload a compliant APK to each track containing the non-compliant APKs.
Be sure to increment the APK version code. If using staged rollout, be sure to set the release to 100% rollout.
For helpful resources, you can:

Learn more about how to provide app privacy and security information for Google Play's Data safety section.
Watch the Google Play PolicyBytes - Data safety form walkthrough.
Check Google Play SDK Index to see if your SDK provider has shared a link to their data safety guidance. Review how any third-party code (such as third-party libraries or SDKs) in your app collects and shares user data.
```

[image]

Note: My app is built with **flutter** and I am using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/platform_device_id) plugin for getting the **device id** of the user, to make sure the user can log in to 2 devices at maximum.

Please suggest a solution so that the app can be updated on the google play store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to App Content -> Data Safety

Next

Check "Does your app collect or share any of the required user data types?"

Answer other required questions (depending on how your app handles the data)

Next

Scroll down and check "Device or other IDs"
[image]

Then submit

Comment: my app does not send anything and i answered all their questions and still get reject b/c somehow they detected it as sending something somewhere w/o providing ANY specifics!

Comment: This is just crazy! I found out that one of my optional text fields, that had a label Email, made them "think" that app was sending emails. So they do not actually check/detect anything! I was pulling my hear out trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error but in my case it was phone number.

`Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Personal Info Data Type - Phone number`

We are using phone number for login and keeping/collecting the phone number for other uses. We did not specify this leading to non-compliance.

You need to go to Data Type and add phone number. This is available in `App Content` at the bottom of hamburger menu[image]